# AFDownloadRequestOperation 206(Partial Content)

Tags: objective-c

need some help.
I download a zip file with library (AFDownloadRequestOperation).
After download is finished it gets only a part of file. Wen I look at code and state, I get a 206(Partial Content). I need whole file, not parts of it. How to solve this problem ? 
Thank you.

CDCBookDownloadOperation extends AFDownloadRequestOperation

```
CDCBookDownloadOperation *operation = [[[CDCBookDownloadOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request targetPath:path book:book] autorelease];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    CDCBookDownloadOperation *bookOperation = (CDCBookDownloadOperation*)operation;
    NSLog(@"success load %d",[bookOperation response].statusCode);
    if ([bookOperation response].statusCode == 206) {

        return ;
    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}]
```

Comment: You need to provide some code where you create the request for us to help you with this aspect

Comment: update text and add code

Answer (score 0):

I fix.
In method - (BOOL)updateByteStartRangeForRequest in AFDownloadRequestOperation
comment line if (downloadedBytes > 0)